# How encode this string to export it to PDF

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, python-3.6, python-unicode, pisa

I'm trying to export to PDF a string containing UTF-8 characters. I have reduced my code to the following code to be able to reproduce it:

```
source = """<html>
            <style>
                @font-face {
                font-family: Preeti;
                src: url("preeti.ttf");
                }

                body {
                font-family: Preeti;
                }
            </style>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            </head>
            <body>
                This is a test <br/>
                       सरल
            </body>
        </html>"""

from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

bytes_result = BytesIO()
pisa.CreatePDF(source, bytes_result, encoding='UTF-8')
result = StringIO(bytes_result.getvalue().decode('UTF-8', 'ignore'))

f = open('test.pdf', 'wt', encoding='utf-8')
f.write(result.getvalue())
```

Which produces the following PDF:

[image]

I have tried a ton of solutions from the internet but I cannot get it right. Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: PDF is a binary format. Why are you trying to save it in text format? If `pisa.CreatePDF()` accepts a writable file as second argument, why don't you do eg. `with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f: pisa.CreatePDF(source, f)`?

Comment: Because I wanted to send that through a view in Django.

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado, did you find a solution in the end?